# Login and password script with each user having a custom page after login

Tags: javascript

so i have a simple script i'm trying to utilize for a side project with multiple users. no real security required just a custom page for each user.

the problem i'm having is getting this script to allow each user/password combo to be redirected to that users custom login page.

ex. Username- Jeff Password- lucky -- if correct go to ...com/users/jeff.htm 
    Username- Sally Password- home -- if correct go to ...com/users/sally.htm 

if anyone can help or has any ideas let me hear em. here is the script i'm trying to use in native form.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

var count = 2;
function validate() {
var un = document.myform.username.value;
var pw = document.myform.pword.value;
var valid = false;

var unArray = ["Philip", "George", "Sarah", "Michael"];  // as many as you like - no     comma after final entry
var pwArray = ["Password1", "Password2", "Password3", "Password4"];  // the corresponding passwords;

for (var i=0; i <unArray.length; i++) {
if ((un == unArray[i]) && (pw == pwArray[i])) {
valid = true;
break;
}
}

if (valid) {
alert ("Login was successful");
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
return false;
}

var t = " tries";
if (count == 1) {t = " try"}

if (count >= 1) {
alert ("Invalid username and/or password.  You have " + count + t + " left.");
document.myform.username.value = "";
document.myform.pword.value = "";
setTimeout("document.myform.username.focus()", 25);
setTimeout("document.myform.username.select()", 25);
count --;
}

else {
alert ("Still incorrect! You have no more tries left!");
document.myform.username.value = "No more tries allowed!";
document.myform.pword.value = "";
document.myform.username.disabled = true;
document.myform.pword.disabled = true;
return false;
}

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will work

```
if(valid)
 {
     window.location=".....com/users/"+ unArray[i] +".html"
 }
```

if the page where you want the user to go is different then you may use another array for users.